# ASP.net Core API returning ActionResult<T> not enforcing return type

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

Where an API is returning an `ActionResult<T>` there is no compile or run-time checks to ensure that the data type being returned is as declared.

For example:

```
public ActionResult<Dog> GetCat()
{
    var cat = new Cat("Moggy");
    return Ok(cat);
}
```

This compiles, runs and returns a Cat object.

The problem I have is that the OpenAPI defintion (Swagger/Swashbuckle) is being derived from the type declared on the method. This means the OpenAPI defintion can be out of sync with the code and there is no obvious way to find these instances.

In the example given, my API documentation would tell people that this API returns a Dog when really it returns a Cat.

Is there any way to enforce the return type at compile time, or failing that at run-time?

Comment: I would call that an error in the API design.  The structure of what an API returns is data.  In Semantically, if the same data grouped has two different meanings, it feels like a definition problem, not an "Swashbuckle isn't deriving my intent correctly" problem.

Comment: What I'm talking about is a genuine developer error - the method is defined to return X (his mistake) but the code is returning Y. The developer won't spot the problem as code compiles and it returns what he expected.

Comment: Unfortunately, not if the developer wraps the object in `Ok()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is because your returned type `OkObjectResult` inherits the `ActionResult`. The returned child class does not impact the Parent class compilation.This is by design.

More details about the two class you could refer to the following source code:

1.The `Ok` method returns type of `OkObjectResult`:

```
// Summary:
//     A base class for an MVC controller without view support.
[Controller]
public abstract class ControllerBase
{       
      // Summary:
    //     Creates an Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.OkObjectResult object that produces an Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.StatusCodes.Status200OK
    //     response.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   value:
    //     The content value to format in the entity body.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     The created Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.OkObjectResult for the response.
    [NonAction]
    public virtual OkObjectResult Ok([ActionResultObjectValueAttribute] object value);
```

2.The `OkObjectResult`  inherits `ObjectResult`:

```
    //
// Summary:
//     An Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ObjectResult that when executed performs content
//     negotiation, formats the entity body, and will produce a Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.StatusCodes.Status200OK
//     response if negotiation and formatting succeed.
[DefaultStatusCode(200)]
public class OkObjectResult : ObjectResult
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Initializes a new instance of the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.OkObjectResult class.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   value:
    //     The content to format into the entity body.
    public OkObjectResult(object value);
}
```

3.The `ObjectResult` inherits `ActionResult`:

```
public class ObjectResult : ActionResult, IStatusCodeActionResult, IActionResult    
{
   public ObjectResult(object value);
   //..
}
```

> Is there any way to enforce the return type at compile time, or failing that at run-time?

`ActionResult<T>` enables you to return a type deriving from `ActionResult` or return a specific type.

To enforce compile error,you could just return cat which is a specific type.And you could see the error message disappear when you change `Dog` to `Cat`:

```
public ActionResult<Dog> GetCat()
{
    var cat = new Cat("Moggy");
    return cat;
}
```

Result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks - so i'll just remove all instances of Ok() and return the actual object. That does leave instances where I'm using other ActionResults like `CreatedAtRoute()` which I'd have to leave.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this feature definitely fails on the [principle of least surprise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) - the reason there's no compile error is that `ActionResult<TValue>` defines an implicit conversion from `ActionResult`, and as [`@Rena`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11398810/rena)'s answer mentions, `OkObjectResult` inherits from `ActionResult`.

```cs
public static implicit operator ActionResult<TValue>(ActionResult result)
{
    return new ActionResult<TValue>(result);
}
```

*from [ActionResultOfT.cs on github](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/db01a95c38c1966664f311d5507c600f210f475d/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ActionResultOfT.cs#L73-L76)*