# How to keep type safety with ActionResult<T> inside API handlers?

Tags: c#

I'm working on a REST API. Inside an API handler I want to send back JSON content, which is either

- Bad Request | NotFound | Conflict | ...
- Success with the actual data

Given the following sample code

```
using Ardalis.ApiEndpoints;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Path.Goes.Here;

public sealed class Handler : EndpointBaseAsync.WithoutRequest.WithResult<ActionResult<List<int>>>
{
    [HttpGet("/my-route")]
    public override async Task<ActionResult<List<int>>> HandleAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
    {
        await Task.CompletedTask;

        if (false)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var data = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };

        return Ok("just a string"); // expecting compile error since string is not List<int>
    }
}
```

I would expect a compile error because I defined a handler that should return `ActionResult<List<int>>` but AFAIK the success result returns `ActionResult<string>`.

How can I make sure the handler can only return what's expected?

Comment: Does this help?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63266409/asp-net-core-api-returning-actionresultt-not-enforcing-return-type TLDR it's because of implicit conversion from the non generic base class. Consider returning the object instead of Ok(object).

Answer (score 0):

`Ok()` takes an `object` parameter and does not know it's type, so it does not trigger a compile-time error.

You could use a typed extension methods to enforce it though.

```
public static ActionResult<T> TypedOk<T>(this ControllerBase controllerBase, T value)
{
    return new OkObjectResult(value);
}
```